# ActiveRecord: Return All Records Without Association That Meets Criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

This is more difficult than it sounds. How can I return all the records of one table that do not have any associated records that meet certain criteria?

For example, I want to get all users who do not have an address history that includes the city of Anchorage (no reason in particular, I love that town).

```
# models
class User
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address
  belongs_to :user
end

# query
# except this returns the wrong set
users = User.joins(:address).where.not(address: { city: 'anchorage' })
users.map { |u| u.addresses.map(&:city) }.flatten.uniq
=> ['detroit', 'anchorage', 'denver']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689363/sql-return-only-records-without-any-associations-that-meet-criteria) in SQL, I was able to create a solution that returned an Active Record collection.

```
User.joins(" LEFT JOIN addresses a
             ON a.user_id = users.id
             AND a.city = 'seattle'
             WHERE a.city IS NULL ")
```