# SQL: Return only records without any associations that meet criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I return only the records that do not have any associated records that meet a certain criteria?

For example, if I have a one to many relationship between users and addresses, how can I get all the users who do NOT have a specific city in their address history?

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f49f/10)

Example data here:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
  (`id` int, `name` varchar(20))
;

CREATE TABLE Addresses
  (`id` int, `city` varchar(20),`user_name` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO Users
  (`id`, `name`)

VALUES
  (1, 'sarah'),
  (2, 'harry'),
;

INSERT INTO Addresses
  (`id`, `city`, `user_name`)

VALUES
  (1, 'denver', 'sarah'),
  (2, 'anchorage', 'sarah'),
  (3, 'providence', 'harry'),
  (4, 'new york', 'harry')
;
```

Comment: ... WHERE City != 'denver'

Comment: @jac In this case, that returns the wrong set of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is with `not exists` or `left join`:

```
select u.*
from users u left join
     addresses a
     on a.username = u.username and
        a.city = 'Peoria'
where a.city is null;
```

The `left join` keeps all records in users and any records in `addresses` that match the `on` conditions.  In this case (because the city name is in the `on` condition), it returns all users with either information about the cities or `NULL` values.  The `where` clause chooses the `NULL` values -- the non-matching ones.

The equivalent `not exists` might be easier to follow:

```
select u.*
from users u 
where not exists (select 1
                  from addresses a
                  where a.username = u.username and
                        a.city = 'Peoria'
                 );
```

Comment: This is the concept that I needed, thank you. I see your book, sitting on my shelf next to me. If I hadn't given up Excel, maybe I would have read it to completion and known the answer to this question!